# Laravel 4 and dojo toolkit AMD implementation how to?

Tags: dojo, laravel-4, amd

is anyone ever tried implementing the dojo toolkit AMD with laravel 4, or could anyone please point me to a simple sample.

1. just a simple AMD implemetation on laravel?
2. What asset manager or the default is ok. how to use it with dojo?

Please help. thanks

Comment: anyone? got any idea's on where can i start to thinker with?

Answer (score 0):

For 1. I suggest you may try this [Laravel 4 bootstrap suite](https://github.com/thomaswelton/laravel) it gives you RequireJS implementation out of the box.

For 2. You can use dojo with any asset manager you want, or even without it (although it is not a good way) - just by putting its .js files in your /public directory and including them as you do in usual html from inside your view templates. If you are using Blade templates make sure the template syntax is not colliding with your js syntax. If it is, then use @include of .php file with your js code section in your .blade.php view template.

Asset manager gives you a more elegant and correct way of doing the same thing. It maybe extremely useful if you are dealing with LESS or Coffee things to be compiled into regular JS and styles. 
If you want advanced asset manager I would suggest your to look at /CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline on github - it's one of many asset managers for Laravel, but one the few keeping alive (take a look at basset or laravel-grunt options on github for instance).

Asset Pipeline makes a good job making asset management similar to the one in Rails. Here is an article on how and why to use it: http://culttt.com/2013/11/04/add-asset-pipeline-laravel-4/